# Como redirecionar para um endpoint da mesma api web api sem usar arquivo de configuração?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp-net-core

Tenho uma Api com dois endpoints:

https://localhost:7001/contas https://localhost:7001/producoes

Ambos estao configurados em um arquivo *appsettings.json* (recomendavel) e quando preciso faço o seguinte:

```
    Var urlContas: _configuration["Evento:UrlContas"];

Var urlProducoes: _configuration["Evento:UrlProducoes"];
 
http.PostAsync(urlContas,context)`;
http.PostAsync(urlProducoes,context)`;
```

**Dúvida:** 
Existe uma alternativa para obter essas `URLs` em tempo real? Tanto em *localhost* como no "servidor" ? 
Ou seja sem a necessidade de usar o appsettings.json ?

Comment: É possível via configuração de proxy-reverso. Existem dois tipos de redirecionamentos com http statusCode 302 (Found) e o 301 (Moved Permanently).